# Regular expression for parsing file extensions in a csv

Tags: java, regex

I am reading lines and need to keep only the part after the file name. I thought of using reg expressions but I can't seem to be able to find a match:
The attempt I made are:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"\\w+\\.jpg\",\\s{1}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("\"0f23af5c71e3f9d7f59ab14277e2023.jpg\", 10.0, 45.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 0.0");
```

Normally I want to parse a `String line` which contain data like:

```
"0f23af5c71e3f9d7f59ab14277e2023.jpg", 10.0, 45.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 0.0
"0f23af5c71e3f9d7f59ab14277e2023.jpg", 139.0, 67.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0
"0f23af5c71e3f9d7f59ab14277e2023.jpg", 205.0, 70.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 4.0, 3.0
```

and keep only the `10.0, 45.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 0.0` etc part in each line.

I can't seem to find a match even for `"` only:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"?"); // or even
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not `split(",")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shall work for you:

```
   String str = "\"0f23af5c71e3f9d7f59ab14277e2023.jpg\", 10.0, 45.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 0.0";
   str = str.replaceAll(".*jpg\",(.*)", "$1");
```

**EDIT**

As per OP's request, here is your modified code, just check the Pattern.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"\\w+\\.jpg\",\\s(.*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("\"0f23af5c71e3f9d7f59ab14277e2023.jpg\", 10.0, 45.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 5.0, 0.0");

    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: Yes it did. I did not get the whole answer (I guess I have yet a lot to learn in regex). The "" is implied in your version?

Comment: Edited my answer with your modified code. see the pattern i replaced `{1}` with `(.*)`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use `replaceAll()` to *remove* the unwanted parts:

```
String numbers = input.replaceAll(".*\", ", "");
```

This deletes (replaces with a blank) everything up to and including "double-quote comma space"

Comment: Your solution worked also but I will choose the first correct answer as the solution. Thanks

Comment: @Eypros Eventhough it's your decision but don't select first correct but always select BEST CORRECT :)

Comment: I have that in mind but I cannot distinguish between those two answers. Both work as expected and I don't have the knowledge to examine other aspects (efficiency etc) so I chose the first posted.

Comment: The difference is the other answer unnecessarily captures in a group `(.*)`, then puts back using a back reference `$1`, the part you want. Mine is the simplest thing that works.